# TFS field set with rule is not saved in history

Tags: tfs

I have created a rule for one work item type when its status is changed, to copy the current time from the clock and save it in custom field. The problem is that this change is not reflected in the item history, which I need.

Any ideas?

Here is the XML for the field at hand:

```
 <FIELD name="Date Closed (Scrum)" refname="Conchango.TeamSystem.Scrum.DateClosed" type="DateTime" reportable="dimension">
    <HELPTEXT>The date that the bug was closed</HELPTEXT>
 </FIELD>
```

and here is its Transition

```
 <TRANSITION from="Ready For Test" to="Done">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Work tested and completed" />
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Conchango.TeamSystem.Scrum.DateClosed">
          <COPY from="clock" />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
 </TRANSITION>
```

Comment: Can you provide your code for this?

Comment: There is no code involved. I introduced the changes with the UI and via the UI I can see that the History of an item is not populated.

Comment: You customise Work Items using XML. This is the code that should be checked into source control. Can you send the xml for the field that you added?

Comment: I have done this with the TFS power pack or whaever it is called, so I did't do any XML. Still I found it and I am updating the question with it.

Comment: Woh... The Conchango process template causes way more problems than it solves! Are you still using the server side components?

Comment: Is the value of the field updated, but not represented in the history?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: The value of the field is updated, but not represented in the history. TFS is version 2012.

Comment: In am not sure that you can do anything about that...

Comment: Do you know if I can execute the transition rule above with some delay e.g. 1 hour after the item is marked as done, then set the field.

Comment: That is not possible.